# How to make Theano use the integrated GPU in MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, installation, theano, gpu

I tried running the test program for GPU usage:

```python
from theano import function, config, shared, tensor, sandbox
import numpy
import time
vlen=10*30*768 #10x #coresx #threadspercore 
iters = 1000
rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)

x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX)) 
f = function([], tensor.exp(x)) 
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(iters): 
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0)) 
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, tensor.Elemwise) and ('Gpu' not in type(x.op).__name__) 
              for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]): 
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gnu')
```

It only shows this (even after installing `libgpuarray`):

```
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 2.723539 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178032  1.61879341  1.52278065 ...,  2.20771815  2.29967753
  1.62323285]
Used the cpu
```

I would like to know how to utilise the integrated GPU of MacBook Air (Early 2014).

My processor has Intel HD Graphics 5000 -- not NVIDIA and hence not CUDA compatible Many [links](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) suggest usage of OpenCL. This was also supposed to be pre-installed with OS-X. But I can't make head or tail out of the links in the web.

I could not find much help of how to set up Theano in the [docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) either.

I just need to make Theano use my Mac's integrated GPU. Is this possible? If so, how? What are its prerequisites?

Comment: How did you run the code? Did you include THEANO_FLAGS=device=gpu?
Anyway, it doesn't seem to me that you'll get a reasonable speedup using a builtin GPU card.

Comment: How to specify these tags, @sygi? Should I do this in the command line? I'm using Ipython notebook for this. Could you please provide a specific instruction for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
THEANO_FLAGS=device=opencl0:1 python ~/check_GPU.py
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!